# How highlight selected item in ListView without clicking?

Tags: android

Have ListView,randomize some integer value and I want highlight this random item. 
But I don't need click on that element. If this possible tell me how it is make. 
[image]

Comment: you can try this , when your app is running , if you want to change data in your list view, simply run a handler that will run after some time , inside the run method call the method which is randomizing your data and then call setListAdapter() method.

Comment: Udit Kapahi, how I can highlight random item?

Comment: can u tell me which type of random item you want exactly

Comment: int min = 65;
int max = 80;

Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
Note that nextInt(int max) returns an int between 0 inclusive and max exclusive.

Comment: I use same type of random:Random generator = new Random();position = generator.nextInt(23)+0; And I want highlight this item

Comment: What is the problem then , and no need to add 0 at the end.

Comment: Problem is that I don't need click on this item, but need highlight it without touching. Sorry that not specific question.

Comment: what you can do is , simply run a handler which contains two things 1. Randomizing Data 2. setListAdapter() , Now run this handler periodically after soe time for ex after 10 secs with the help of Timer class . This will randomize your list after certain period of time.

Comment: If you correctly understand me I want make something like on the picture above. I don't need randomize my list, need highlight some random item in this list.